# Looping through array of songs html5 audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Loop stops at end when entire playsite is played, but it won't restart and set currentSong to 1? I have 8 songs in my array, it loops through each of them and plays them, when they end they call NextSong, but when the last song plays nothing happens.

```
function NextSong()
{
    alert("next song");
    document.removeEventListener('ended',NextSong);

    if(rewindClicked ==true)
    {
        currentSong--;
    }
    else
    {
        currentSong++;
    }

    if(currentSong > songList.length)
    {
        currentSong = 1; 
    }

    if(currentSong < 1)
    {
        currentSong = songList.length; 
    }

    songList[currentSong].play();
    rewindClicked = false;

    //song.addEventListener('ended', NextSong);
    songList[currentSong].addEventListener('ended', NextSong);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrary indexes start from 0.

```
if(currentSong > songList.length)
{
    currentSong = 1;
}

songList[currentSong].play();
```

This part allows `currentSong` to be exactly the array's length, which means `songList[currentSong]` tries to access an element out of bounds, which you might see in the JavaScript error console. In other words, if there are 8 songs in the array, `songList[ 7 ]` is the last of them.

Change the conditional to:

```
if(currentSong >= songList.length)
```

Similarly you might want to change

```
if(currentSong < 1)
{
    currentSong = songList.length; 
}
```

to

```
if(currentSong < 0)
{
    currentSong = songList.length - 1; 
}
```

Comment: also noticed: if(currentSong >= songList.length)
{
currentSong = 0;

}